# Limit only one record entry in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list where I need to only create one record. After creating the record in that particular list we should not able to add a new entry in that list.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot quite see the reason, but the easiest way is to change the security for the list after you have inserted the item, so noone is permitted to add items